# SQL commands generated in Django by running sqlall

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django app, I just ran

```
$ python manage.py sqlall
```

and I see a lot of SQL statements that look like this, when describing FK relationships:

```
ALTER TABLE `app1_model1` ADD CONSTRAINT model2_id_refs_id_728de91f FOREIGN KEY (`model2_id`) REFERENCES `app1_model2` (`id`);
```

Where does "7218de91f" come from?  I would like to know because I'd like to manually write SQL statements to accompany models changes in the app so that my db's can be kept up to date.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a migration app to write all your SQL for you. It's definitely the smart way to go. Check out [South](http://south.aeracode.org) -- part of it will be merged into Django core soon